# Select best score in course with lambda

Tags: linq, lambda

This table stores student course name and score. I want to create a lambda expression to choose the best student in each course

```
ID | name | courseName | score
------------------------------
 1 | Alex |   Math     | 18
 2 | John |   physics  | 19
 3 | Sam  |   Math     | 17
 4 | Sarah|   physics  | 14
```

The desired result

```
ID | name | courseName | score
------------------------------
 1 | Alex |    Math    |18
 2 | John |    Physics |19
```

Comment: What if there are multiple students with same max score?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I want choice max score in any course in this sample math max score is 18 and student name is Alex and in Physics course max score is 19 and student name is John

Comment: No, my question was meant differently. What students to do you want if `Math` has two students with score 18?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy`:

```
var query = students
    .GroupBy(s => s.CourseName )
    .Select(cg => cg.OrderByDescending(s => s.Score).First());
```

That picks the best student of each course. If there are multiple with the same max-score you get an arbitrary student. You could use this to select all max-students:

```
IEnumerable<Student> query = students
    .GroupBy(s => s.CourseName)
    .SelectMany(cg => cg.GroupBy(s => s.Score).OrderByDescending(g => g.Key).First());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer bu when is use first after OrderBy... compiler return error to me "The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead" To correct this Error change First to FirstOrDefault

Comment: @imanmir: it seems that your LINQ provider (f.e. Linq-To-Entities) doesn't support `First` in the middle of the query. So then use `FirstOrdefault` as suggested.